# Specific Date but increase Year based on GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm using SQL Server.

I have a specific date (in dd/mm/yyyy format) i.e. 06/04/2020

However, in a T-SQL View, it needs to be always 1 year from now i.e. if I run today it would return 06/04/2021.  And if it executed in 2021 it would return 06/04/2022 - how would I do this?

So I can run the below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(year, 1, '06/04/2020'), 103) as MyDate;
```

Which will give me:

```
2021-06-04
```

However, how do I make it self-maintaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it generic by extracting the year from `GETDATE()`, adding 1 and concatenating that to `06/04` (or the date as required), and then converting. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('06/04/', DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) + 1), 103)
```

Output:

```
2021-04-06
```